# Next.js - Styled Components styled break on the server

Tags: javascript, next.js, styled-components

I'm working with Next.js and styled-components. When I run locally, everything works fine. When I run in production, the styles break for the first second, then load. See screenshots below.

I'm using a custom _document.js and following Next's sample repo with styled components.

Code

```
import Document from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

try {
  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
        sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
    })

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: (
      <>
        {initialProps.styles}
        {sheet.getStyleElement()}
      </>
    ),
  }
} finally {
  sheet.seal()
}
  }
}
```

**First Load**

[image: First Load]

**After a Second**

[image]

Comment: Hi! Have you found any solution? I think I have the same problem. Thanks.